# VBScript in HTML/PHP pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, debugging, vbscript

I want to use VBScript in HTML/PHP pages, and I've searched until I found that I can reference the VBScript via `<script type="text/vbscript">...</script>`. Yet when I try it, nothing appears on the browser.

So is there a way to enable this, or should I convert the VBScript to JavaScript? If the only way is conversion, then I want a tutorial for the VB functions or someone to help me with understanding the code.

Comment: Im gonna guess that vbcript is a typo?

Comment: you could try `<script language="vbscript"></script>` but I'm willing to bet that this would be IE only

Comment: Or that could be the reason why it's not working.

Comment: VBScript will only work in IE; no other browser supports it. It is also considered obsolete even in IE; if it works at all in newer versions of IE, it'll be an ancient version of VBScript; I doubt it's been updated in ten years. You would be **much** better off sticking with Javascript.

Comment: Well, I'm using Google Chrome to test the page that I`m writing. I guess I`m gonna change everything to JS. But is there a reference to the VB codes/functions so that I can understand them and be able to convert them to JS? Ir can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [syntax reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt), [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn374734.aspx), [DOM reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757850), and [conversion tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756007) to port the code to JavaScript, JScript, or ECMAScript5.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to PHP, but if the browser is IE11 then VBScript is not supported
(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn384057(v=vs.94)).

However, I believe if you include the following compatibility tag in the html HEAD the script should work in HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```